# Cassandra - select query with token() function

Tags: cassandra, token, cql

According to [this](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause) documentation, I was trying a select query with token() function in it, but it gives wrong results.

I am using below cassandra version

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.2.5 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]
```

I was trying token query for below table -

```
CREATE TABLE price_key_test (
    objectid int,
    createdOn bigint,
    price int,
    foo text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((objectid, createdOn), price));
```

Inserted data --

```
insert into nasa.price_key_test (objectid,createdOn,price,foo) values (1,1000,100,'x');
insert into nasa.price_key_test (objectid,createdOn,price,foo) values (1,2000,200,'x');
insert into nasa.price_key_test (objectid,createdOn,price,foo) values (1,3000,300,'x');
```

Data in table --

```
 objectid | createdon | price | foo
----------+-----------+-------+-----
        1 |      3000 |   300 |   x
        1 |      2000 |   200 |   x
        1 |      1000 |   100 |   x
```

Select query is  --

```
select * from nasa.price_key_test
    where token(objectid,createdOn) > token(1,1000)
      and token(objectid,createdOn) < token(1,3000);
```

This query suppose to return row with `createdOn` 2000, but it returns zero rows.

```
 objectid | createdon | price | foo
----------+-----------+-------+-----

(0 rows)
```

According to my understanding, `token(objectid,createdOn)` > `token(1,1000)` and `token(objectid,createdOn) < token(1,3000)` should select row with partition key with value 1 and 2000.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: According to the article you pointed to, the token function can only be used the way you intended when ByteOrderedPartitioner is selected for the cluster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try flipping your greater/less-than signs around:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM price_key_test 
    WHERE token(objectid,createdOn) < token(1,1000) 
    AND token(objectid,createdOn) > token(1,3000) ;

 objectid | createdon | price | foo
----------+-----------+-------+-----
        1 |      2000 |   200 |   x

(1 rows)
```

Adding the `token()` function to your SELECT should help you to understand why:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT objectid, createdon, token(objectid,createdon), 
    price, foo FROM price_key_test ;

 objectid | createdon | system.token(objectid, createdon) | price | foo
----------+-----------+-----------------------------------+-------+-----
        1 |      3000 |              -8449493444802114536 |   300 |   x
        1 |      2000 |              -2885017981309686341 |   200 |   x
        1 |      1000 |              -1219246892563628877 |   100 |   x

(3 rows)
```

The hashed token values generated are not necessarily proportional to their original numeric values.  In your case, `token(1,3000)` generated a hash that was the *smallest* of the three, and not the largest.

Comment: @Aron Thanks for reply sir. That mean we cannot relay on token() function. Can you tel us when can we use token in select query.

Comment: @Gunwant `token()` makes sense when you want to query a large table in its entirety.  Typically, queries for large result sets will time-out, so you could query a token range at a time to make it more likely to succeed.